# How to remove colons in Form.input antd design react?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Ant design always has colons after label in form input.
Is it possible to remove that?

https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-layout

[image]

Comment: use another framework like material UI or just make your own

Answer (score 19, accepted):

set colon prop for form tag to false

```
  <Form
    colon={false}
   >

  </Form>
```

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. I found in antd documentation about this but did not know how to set this actually.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it by using css

```
        .ant-form-item label:after {
          content: none;
        }
```

By the way, AntD doesn't show the colon on mobile.

Comment: Use antd APIs first. They have option to set attribute colon={false} in Form.Item.